# Why is socket.io event firing multiple times from react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I have a connect event where, once i login, I always get to the homescreen and on the homescreen's useEffect, I have socket.io client side "connect" event as follows. The localStorage authToken was set on the Login Screen after the password matched. I see the connect event fires multiple times even when I turned off React Strict Mode.

The problem seems to be on the client side as the console.log on the second useEffect fires multiple times.
How should I set up socket.io so it only fires one time after HomeScreen render?

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(localStorage.getItem('authToken') && !localStorage.getItem('showedLoginStatus')){
            toast.success("Login successful!");
            localStorage.setItem('showedLoginStatus', 'showed');
        }

        setSocket(io.connect(backendLink));
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(socket, localStorage.getItem('authToken'));
        socket?.emit("newUser", localStorage.getItem('authToken'));
    }, [socket, localStorage.getItem('authToken')])
```

The backend socket.io code is as follows:

```
            socket.on("newUser", async (jwtToken) => {
                const user = await findUserFromJWT(jwtToken);
                addNewUser(user._id, socket.id);
                console.log('connect print'); printUsers();
            })
```

Console.log on the server side after only 1 Login:

```
connect print
{
  userID: new ObjectId("6243ff45c46997fa04ea6e29"),
  socketID: '_-9y81H4P7PaUt19AAAB'
}
{
  userID: new ObjectId("6243ff45c46997fa04ea6e29"),
  socketID: 'cjU_JmCqUOMF619PAAAH'
}
```

Comment: Is it happening because of the server restarting? How to make sure that is not the case?

Comment: What happens if you remove  localStorage.getItem('authToken') from useEffect's dependencies?

Comment: It's the same because on all the console.log on the second useEffect, the authToken is always there as in unchanged

Comment: Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. First time the second useEffect renders, the socket is null so I'm guessing it shouldn't emit because of socket?. Then the second useEffect renders with valid socket, and this is the last time the second useEffect fires so how come there are multiple event calls triggering on the server?

Comment: What if the optional chaining is messing things up ? Try to encapsulate your ``socket.emit()`` in a ``if(!!socket){}`` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure but, looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61178240/useeffect-does-not-listen-for-localstorage) it seems like putting localStorage in useEffect dependencies is not the best idea.

To solve the double call though, in my experience, it is better to use a state to track whether the newUser call was done:

```
const [newUserRegistered, setNewUserRegistered] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    const setNewUser = () => {
        if(window.localStorage('newUser') && socket && !newUserRegistered){
            //do your socket thing, then
            setNewUserRegistered(true);
        }
    }
    
    window.addEventListener('storage', setNewUser);

    return() => {
        window.removeEventListener('storage', setNewUser)
    }
}, [socket, newUserRegistered])
```